# How do I use Search-AzGraph to join resources to app insights

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-application-insights

For all my resources,  I am trying to run a report that shows me the application insight that connect to the resource so I know if any resources are not configured to use app insights, and that they are using the correct one.  For example,  using the portal, looking at the Application Insights blade for a function app,  I can see what app insight resource it is linked to.  I want to report on that for all applicable resources. [image]

I am listing all resources in a set of resource groups.  For each of the resources, I want to report on a number of configuration values, one of which is the app insight resource that each resource uses.  To do this I'm trying to join my resources to the related app insight resource based on the InstrumentationKey.

```
$query = "Resources | where resourceGroup in ($resourceGroupFilter) 
    | extend OS = case(tolower(properties.reserved) == 'true', 'Linux', tolower(properties.reserved) == 'false', 'Windows', '$notApplicable') 
    | extend HttpsOnly = properties.httpsOnly or properties.supportsHttpsTrafficOnly 
    | extend PublicAccess = properties.allowBlobPublicAccess 
    | extend MinTLS = properties.minimumTlsVersion 
    | extend Settings = properties.SiteConfig 
    | extend InstrumentationKey = tostring(properties.InstrumentationKey)
    | join kind=leftouter (Resources | where type == 'microsoft.insights/components' | project InstrumentationKey = tostring(properties.InstrumentationKey)) on InstrumentationKey
    | order by name asc" 

$resources = Search-AzGraph -query $query
```

I think the problem is how I am trying to retrieve the InstrumentationKey for each resource.  If I just try to report on the Instrumentation key of each of my resources, the only ones that seem to have one are the app insight resources themselves, even though I know some of my functions, service bus, etc have app insights configured.

```
$query = "Resources | where resourceGroup in ($resourceGroupFilter) 
    | extend OS = case(tolower(properties.reserved) == 'true', 'Linux', tolower(properties.reserved) == 'false', 'Windows', '$notApplicable') 
    | extend HttpsOnly = properties.httpsOnly or properties.supportsHttpsTrafficOnly 
    | extend PublicAccess = properties.allowBlobPublicAccess 
    | extend MinTLS = properties.minimumTlsVersion 
    | extend Settings = properties.SiteConfig 
    | extend InstrumentationKey = tostring(properties.InstrumentationKey)\
    | order by name asc" 

$resources = Search-AzGraph -query $query
```

Comment: your functions app might have more than one function those functions(might be service bus trigger, http trigger or other triggers) those functions will be connected to single application insights may that is the reason you are seeing one application insights as output when you run the 1st query on azure function resources

Comment: Also, can you elaborate more what exactly you are trying to do with sample image of expected results and what you are seeing that would be helpful to understand better

Comment: @VenkateshDodda - 

For all my resources, I am trying to run a report that shows me the application insight that connect to the resource so I know if any resources are not configured to use app insights, and that they are using the correct one. For example, using the portal, looking at the Application Insights blade for a function app, I can see what app insight resource it is linked to. I want to report on that for all applicable resources.